# Reproducir audio y video obtenido desde un capturador de video con JS

Tags: javascript, video, audio

Estoy reproduciendo el audio y video que obtengo de un capturador de video HDMI, el video se reproduce sin problema pero el audio al iniciar se entre corta, luego mejora, pero se entre corta intermitentemente.

He tratado de configurar el buffer, o con algunas librerías pero tengo el mismo resultado con el audio.

Mi código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Show video</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor_devices">
        <h1 class="h1_title">Selecciona un Dispositivo de Video</h1>
        <select id="videoDevices" class="select_devices"></select>
        <button id="btn_reproducir">Reproducir</button>
    </div>
    <div id="contenedor_video" style="display: none;">
        <div class="first-row">
            <div class="column" style="background-color: white; text-align: center;">
                
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-row" style="background-color: red;">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi código JS:
Obtengo los dispositivos de entrada de video, en el cual se lista mi cámara web y mi capturador de video.

```
const mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices;
const select = document.getElementById('videoDevices');
const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
let audioContext;
let audioStream;

async function getVideoDevices() {
    try {
        const devices = await mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
        const videoDevices = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput');

        videoDevices.forEach(device => {
            const option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = device.deviceId;
            option.text = device.label || `Dispositivo ${select.options.length + 1}`;
            select.appendChild(option);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al obtener los dispositivos de video:', error);
    }
}



getVideoDevices();

$('#btn_reproducir').click(function(){
    $('#contenedor_devices').hide();
    $('#contenedor_video').show();
    startVideo();
});

async function startVideo() {
    try {
        const deviceId = select.value;
        if (videoPlayer.srcObject) {
            videoPlayer.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        }

        if (audioContext) {
            audioContext.close();
        }

        audioContext = new AudioContext();
        const videoStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: false, video: { deviceId } });

        const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(videoStream);
        audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
        audioSource.connect(audioStream);

        videoPlayer.srcObject = videoStream;
        videoPlayer.play();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al iniciar el video:', error);
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo mejorar la reproducción de audio sin afectar la reproducción del video?